# NegativeArraySizeException in CacheDispatcher.java:99

Tags: android, android-volley

NegativeArraySizeException

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1105
at com.android.volley.toolbox.d.a(DiskBasedCache.java:300)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.d.a(DiskBasedCache.java:115)
at com.android.volley.d.run(CacheDispatcher.java:99)
```

Comment: post complete logcat and also if you have changed source code post that too !

Comment: Are you still able to trigger this error? Generally a `NegativeArraySizeException` in library code (such as `DiskBasedCache`) indicates an integer overflow bug.

Answer (score 1):

As per the link below, "There is a parallelism happening that when cache dispatcher thread is executing get method of Diskcache, the cached file is deleted by the Android OS for clean up. As OS can delete cache files from cache directory to reclaim space."

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/volley-users/0W-oI6za8VY

Answer (score -1):

This is due to transferring data over socket or another network connection, firstly reset your Connection.

Comment: How do you know it is network issue.. Please add more details to answer