# Android RecycleView Scrolls to Top when it Loads data

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview

I want to implement Pagination in my app using Recycleview, I used the `addOnScrollListener` to check if i get to last cell as shown below .

The data is loading with out any issue but when i scroll to last cell the Recycleview will automatically scroll back to the top of the list ! and the toast message (**end of list**) will keep popup continuously ?

This is class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int pageno = 0;
    ArrayList<carobject> carslist = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView RV;
    adapter listadapter;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainrv);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        RV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
       loaddata(pageno);
        RV.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                int pastVisibleItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if (pastVisibleItems + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "end of list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pageno +=1;
                    loaddata(pageno);
                    RV.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

    }
public void loaddata(final int pagetoloaad){
// load data from API using Volley........

listadapter = new adapter(MainActivity.this,carslist);
                            RV.setAdapter(listadapter);
    }
```

**UPDATE :**

I have removed below code to on create method

```
listadapter = new adapter(MainActivity.this,carslist);
RV.setAdapter(listadapter);
```

and replace it with

```
RV.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The auto scroll to top issue is solved but i'm getting app crash when keep scrolling to buttom

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -652
at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:323)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.get(DiskBasedCache.java:119)
at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:100)
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: Where have you called method 'setAdapter()' ??

Comment: In loaddata function after deserializing the JSON objects 

`listadapter = new adapter(MainActivity.this,carslist);
                            RV.setAdapter(listadapter); `

Comment: ok, are you done with 'scroll' issue?
'NegativeArraySizeException' is something else, probably you are getting this after webservice call.

this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290804/negativearraysizeexception-in-cachedispatcher-java99

Comment: I can't find the main problem, all search results points to Volley bug !!!

Answer (score 2):

As `listadapter = new adapter(MainActivity.this,carslist);
                            RV.setAdapter(listadapter);` is calling from **loaddata(pageno)** method, **instance of adapter getting created every time when you scroll recyclerview and call loaddata() method**.

So instantiate adapter once in 'onCreate()' only. it will solve your problem.

Let me know in the comment if you still need any help.

Comment: thanks for your replay, but i already did what you mentioned and the crash issue raised now , plz check the update

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

save restore the state when u set adapter

```
private Parcelable recyclerViewState;

public void loaddata(final int pagetoloaad){
// load data from API using Volley........

listadapter = new adapter(MainActivity.this,carslist);
                            RV.setAdapter(listadapter);
RV.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
    }
```

and then save the state when you call load data

```
recyclerViewState = RV.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
pageno +=1;
                    loaddata(pageno);
                    RV.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue of the `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -652` is solved after using the Queue Singleton for volley.

```
public class Singleton extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = Singleton.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static Singleton mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
Singleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest,"Your Tag");
```

And don't forget to add the Singleton class to your manifest file

Hope to help some one